# Подготовка запроса MySQL (ALTER TABLE)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Не выходит подготовить запрос **MySQL (ALTER TABLE)** и сделать следующие.

Есть список таблиц, в таблицах есть `Column Name` (напр.`"post_date","post_content"` и тд.) у них есть значения (напр.`"varchar","int"` и тд.)

Нужно:

Пройтись по всем таблицам и найти в них `Column Name` (напр. `"post_date","post_content"`) у которых значения `"datetime"` и создать запрос 
`MySQL (ALTER TABLE)`.

Что в итоге должно получиться:

**

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_posts` 
CHANGE COLUMN `post_date` `post_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' ,
CHANGE COLUMN `post_date_gmt` `post_date_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01';
```

**
    **

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_comments` 
    CHANGE COLUMN `comments_date` `comments_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01' ,
    CHANGE COLUMN `comments_date_gmt` `comments_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-01 00:00:01';
```

**

И так далее пока не переберет всю базу.

Мой запрос переберает базу но не подставляет `Column Name`, не могу разобраться почему. Пробую разные вариации, но пока безуспешно :(

**

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', t.`TABLE_SCHEMA`, '`.`', t.`TABLE_NAME`, '` CHANGE COLUMN `', d.`column_name`, d.`column_name`, '` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT \'1970-01-01 00:00:01\';')
AS sqlcode
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` t, `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` d
WHERE t.`table_name` 
LIKE 'wp_%' 
AND d.`COLUMN_TYPE` = 'datetime'
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

**

Comment: А нафига тут нужна INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES? В INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS есть всё необходимое для построения текста запроса...

Comment: Делал с примера взятого с инета

Comment: Т.е. тупо слизал, поленившись разобраться. Жаль... думаю, когда разберёшься, вопрос задавать и не понадобится... попробуй.

Comment: Если бы "слизал", написал бы сразу, а так взял за пример, модифицировал, пробую разные варианты. Отдельно выборку сделал, могу отдельно все сделать уже написанным мной запрос, его я и скинул самым первым. Но, вопрос, как массово сделать, чтобы не дергать руками каждую таблицу для меня сложность пока, разбираюсь целый день, до конца не могу понять, вот и прошу помощи.

Comment: Хранимая процедура. Курсор по INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS с необходимыми условиями отбора. Для каждой записи - построение запроса и его выполнение через Prepared statement.

Comment: Или, если хочется всё это делать с клиента. Запрос в INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS с необходимыми условиями отбора, получение (TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME) в массив. Перебор массива, для каждой записи формирование запроса и его выполнение.

Answer (score 0):

Мое решение, которое помогло:

**

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('ALTER TABLE `', `table_schema`, '`.`',`table_name`, ' CHANGE COLUMN `', `column_name`, '` `', `column_name`, ' `DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT \'1970-01-01 00:00:01\';')
AS sqlcode
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE `table_name` LIKE 'wp_%' 
AND `COLUMN_TYPE` = 'datetime'
LIMIT 0, 30;
```

**

Comment: Зачем вам это могло понадобиться? Пытаетесь "оптимизировать" WordPress?

Comment: В таблице нужно поменять кодировку с ```utf8``` на ```utf8mb4```, но кодировка не меняется если по дефолту есть значение у column_name ```DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'```